# Customize the Current Location Icon with HERE Maps

Tags: android, here-api

Are there any APIs for changing the look of the current location icon used during navigation. I was able to modify it using a custom Map marker and updating the position using the position manager callbacks but I'm wondering if there is an easier way. Also it wasn't clear how I could change the heading of the icon (I'm replacing the circle with an arrow). I'd like to be able to rotate the arrow appropriately during maneuvers. It looks as if the HERE app does this sort of thing so I'm wondering if any of these APIs are exposed in the SDK.

Comment: Here's an example (source code) how to do it with the HERE MobileSDK on app level (since the default Position indicator is limited to basic functionality only): https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/CustomPositionMarker.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally we encourage developers to build their own position indicators using the MapMarker or MapLocalModel APIs. There are too many customization options for us to make a generic position indicator :)

Please create a map object and customize the behaviour as needed for your application.

Comment: how can we customize here maps navigation icon using here maps APIs in Android? I need to change the default navigation icon to a car icon.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an Image objects

```
Image img = new Image();
try {
   img.setImageResource(R.drawable.marker);
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you have to make sure that you add those two lines:

```
mapFragment.getPositionIndicator().setVisible(true);
mapFragment.getPositionIndicator ().setMarker (img);
```

It worked for me like this.